# Laws About Contributions from Business You Own to 501c(3) You Founded/Work At

Tags: business, non-profit, charity, conflict-of-interest, fiduciary-duties

I have a US LLC I own, and am interested in beginning a charitable non-profit organization, to operate as a 501 3 (c) that would operate in a tangentially related area. When there is similar overlap and management of a non-profit what enhanced rules and standards exist that directors must follow?

**As I understand there can be collaboration with related businesses but I dont see what the test is for upholding your duties as director.**

Let's say a fellow director was in a similar situation where the business they run can materially contribute in useful ways to the non-profits goals (the type of person you might try to bring on as a director), would their contributions be considered conflicts of interest since a byproduct of their donations could be a tax write-off for example?

**What set of practices should a non-profit that has overlap with other business management be expected to follow and how does that enhance on the standard legal responsibilities of a director/non-profit management? What is the line drawn for acting in self-interest, for example when it comes to donated collaborations of various types?**

Comment: Are you mixing up non-profit (charitable) organization with a "not-for-profit" organization? I don't know of any blockchain companies running a 501(c)3...

Comment: I may have mixed up on the blockchain example since I'm unaware of the details there. I was kind of hoping to find an example that clearly illustrated business/non-profit collaboration and my brain defaulted to that, so if I'm mistakened then I'll delete that example.

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule is that no person or entity, other than (1) another non-profit within the scope of the charitable purpose of a non-profit or (2) someone whose benefit is within the scope of the charitable purpose of a non-profit, may derive economic benefit, in excess of fair market value for goods or services provided to the non-profit. As the [IRS explains it](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/charitable-organizations/exemption-requirements-501c3-organizations):

> To be tax-exempt under section 501(c)(3) of the Internal Revenue Code,
> an organization must be organized and operated exclusively for exempt
> purposes set forth in section 501(c)(3), and none of its earnings may
> inure to any private shareholder or individual. In addition, it may
> not be an action organization, i.e., it may not attempt to influence
> legislation as a substantial part of its activities and it may not
> participate in any campaign activity for or against political
> candidates.
>
> Organizations described in section 501(c)(3) are commonly referred to
> as charitable organizations. Organizations described in section
> 501(c)(3), other than testing for public safety organizations, are
> eligible to receive tax-deductible contributions in accordance with
> Code section 170.
>
> The organization must not be organized or operated for the benefit of
> private interests, and no part of a section 501(c)(3) organization's
> net earnings may inure to the benefit of any private shareholder or
> individual. If the organization engages in an excess benefit
> transaction with a person having substantial influence over the
> organization, an excise tax may be imposed on the person and any
> organization managers agreeing to the transaction.
>
> Section 501(c)(3) organizations are restricted in how much political
> and legislative (lobbying) activities they may conduct.

Economic benefit, for this purpose, does not include tax code authorized deductions or credits associated with donations to the non-profit. Instead, the notion is to not enter into deals that are unduly favorable to the party dealing with the non-profit, and to not provide excessive perks and compensation to individuals workin with the non-profit that are more favorable than the prevailing non-profit management market.

Non-profits routinely can and do have directors and officers of for-profit companies that support them on their boards of directors. When acting in that capacity, the directors and officers owe a duty of loyalty to the non-profit, and can't put the interests of other businesses with which they are involved above the interests of the non-profit.

The regulations are more specific, and there are some additional requirements that are imposed, in the case of a 501(c)(3) that is a "[private foundation](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/private-foundations)" (which is defined, more or less, as receiving most of its donations from a small number of big donors who aren't non-profits themselves). For example, a private foundation is required to spend a certain amount determined by a formula each year for charitable purposes, rather than reinvesting all investment returns and donations for future use. As [the IRS explains](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/charitable-organizations/private-foundations):

> [T]here are several restrictions and requirements on private
> foundations, including:
>
> 1. restrictions on self-dealing between private foundations and their substantial contributors and other disqualified persons;
> 2. requirements that the foundation annually distribute income for charitable purposes;
> 3. limits on their holdings in private businesses;
> 4. provisions that investments must not jeopardize the carrying out of exempt purposes; and
> 5. provisions to assure that expenditures further exempt purposes.

The IRS provides a detailed description of what constitutes a self-dealing transaction at [this link](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/private-foundations-self-dealing-irc-4941d1b). Loans of money between the non-profit and related parties are particularly perilous.